# Python3 crossplatform GUI toolkit

Tags: qt4, python-3.x, pyside, gtk3, gtkbuilder

I need a OSX and GNU/Linux compatible GUI toolkit which works with python3.

I tried GTK3 with GObject introspection, but it was hard to be deployed on OSX.
Is there something like gtk builder compatible which will run on OSX ?

What my requirements are:

- XML based layout with an IDE builder
- Runs on OSX (and be compatible or works out of the box on GNU/Linux)
- Works on Python3
- Not ugly as TK :) (kidding)

Answer (score 2):

You can use Qt in Python with PyQt. The advantage over Gtk is that it looks native on OS X (Qt uses Cocoa for rendering.)

More info: http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/intro/

If you're using Homebrew, you can install it quite easily:

```
brew install pyqt
```

Or you might find binaries on the [PyQtX project page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqtx/).

Comment: I tried, but it requires a commercial or trial licence on  OS X.

Comment: Do you mean Qt? It's available under the LGPL. You don't need a commercial license. You can use it even if your application is not open source.

Comment: PyQt or PySide definitely tick all the boxes. The only major difference between them is the licensing - PyQt is GPL, PySide is LGPL.

Answer (score 0):

There aren't any that I know of. Is the Python 3 requirement necessary? If not, you might consider [Qt](http://qt.digia.com) and the [PySide](http://qt-project.org/wiki/PySide) bindings, or Enthought's [TraitsUI](http://code.enthought.com/projects/traits_ui/) framework which builds on either Wx or Qt.

Answer (score 0):

Final solution:

python3 using pyqt

1. download the following MacOS pkg:

   http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqtx/files/Complete/
2. After installation

   we run the following sample python3 program:

Code to use:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, uic
```

if we don't have any import error, then pyqt is **working** properly.

Tested on MacOS Lion **10.7.2**

on GNU/Linux Python3 should have pyqt already working out of the box.
Tested on Archlinux.